# Mockito: verify a method with exception called multiple times

Tags: mockito

Could anyone advise on the following? I have a method that throws an exception if nothing found in the database and this is business requirement. Also, method has retry implemented via Spring xml AOP. So that, the method should run several times and then fail with exception. Is there any way to use Mockito for to count the number of times the method was called?

This one doesn't work:

```
verify(mock, times(5)).method();
```

Because the final method invocation throws exception and this exception fails the verifying itself. I tried `@Test(expected = ...)` but it just catches the final exception and skips verification.

Comment: Is there a benefit to knowing it failed 5 times vs it failed overall? You shouldn't be testing that the library's built in method repeater is working, that's the job of the library developers to test

Comment: Could you attach the tested method and the test method you've written that fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```java
    package de.test;
    public class MyService {
      int invocations = 0;
      public void doSomething(int x){
        invocations++;
        if (invocations==5){
          throw new RuntimeException("exception");
        }
        return;
      };
    }

    package de.test;
    
    public class MyProcessor {
      private MyService myService;
    
      public MyProcessor(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
      }
    
      public void process(int n) {
        myService.doSomething(n);
        System.out.println("Processed: " + n);
      }
    }
```

And this Testcode:

```java
  package de.test;
    
  import de.bodo.MyProcessor;
  import de.bodo.MyService;
  import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
  import org.mockito.Mockito;
    
  public class ProcessorTest {

    @Test
    public void processTest() {
      MyService myService = Mockito.spy(new MyService());
      MyProcessor myProcessor = new MyProcessor(myService);
      
      myProcessor.process(0);
      myProcessor.process(1);
      myProcessor.process(2);
      myProcessor.process(2);
      RuntimeException thrown = assertThrows( RuntimeException.class,
         ()-> myProcessor.process(2),
         " expected exception" );
      myProcessor.process(2);
    
      Mockito.verify(myService, Mockito.atMostOnce()).doSomething(0);
      Mockito.verify(myService, Mockito.atMostOnce()).doSomething(1);
      Mockito.verify(myService, Mockito.atMost(4)).doSomething(2);
      Mockito.verify(myService, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).doSomething(1);
      Mockito.verify(myService, Mockito.atLeast(2)).doSomething(2);
      Mockito.verify(myService, Mockito.times(4)).doSomething(2);
      Mockito.verify(myService, Mockito.never()).doSomething(3);    
    }
  }
```

So you can not only check how often a method was called, but even you can count how often a method was call with one specific argument (the integer number in this example.)

You need to add Mockito to your pom.xml:

```xml
        !-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Source: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/unit-testing/mockito/verifying-varing-number-of-invocations.html